# Create file of array list

Tags: java, file, file-io, arraylist

How to create the file in Java? 
If I have the data add by array list 
and I want the save of file and if enter new user information will be saved in the file.

Can I write?

```
ArrayList<Example> e= new ArrayList<Example>();
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in) ;

FileWriter writ = new FileWriter ("Example.txt" ) 

writ.write("Hello \n" + e.add(new Example("jack","USA","12345"))); //if the date exist

writ.write("Hello \n" + e.add(new Example(input.nextLine(),input.nextLine(),input.nextLine()))); //if user inter data
```

And if no data is added, what's error that?

Comment: e.add is going to return void, so nothing will be written after Hello.  You need to print the Example object you are adding.  You are going to want to override toString() in your Example class so that it can be printed properly.

Comment: 1) There is no need to add the major tag in the title. 2) Please add an upper case letter at the start of sentences.  Also use a capital for the word I, and abbreviations and acronyms like JEE or WAR.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help. 3) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 4) *"Can I write?"*  What happened when you *tried it?*  Your compiler/run-time can provide answers faster and more accurately than we can.

Comment: Your question doesn't make it clear why your using an ArrayList. Do you need to store the 'Example' and write it to a file on the same time? Or simply add them all to the ArrayList, then save it to a file?

Answer (score 0):

You should `close()` your file to save data.

```
ArrayList<Example> e= new ArrayList<Example>();
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); //Add semicolon
FileWriter writ = new FileWriter ("Example.txt"); 
writ.write("Hello \n" + e.add(new Example("jack","USA","12345")));
   // e.add will return true if add() is success
....
writ.close(); //Close the file after write
```

Comment: And the reason why it writes 'true' is that an ArrayList's add() method returns true if the object is added and false if not. So as specified by Collection.add(E), it will return true, as you would receive an exception if the object couldn't be added.

Answer (score 0):

To give you an example I will add all elements to the ArrayList and then print it, I believe that's what your trying to achieve, right?

```
ArrayList<Example> e= new ArrayList<Example>();
e.add(new Example("jack","USA","12345"));
e.add(new Example("jones","USA","52365"));

FileWriter writ = new FileWriter ("Example.txt" );

for(Example item : e){
    writ.write("Hello \n" + item.toString()); // If you have overridden toString()
}

writ.close(); // Flush and close the file!
```

That's a simple example... Remeber to override toString() on your Example class, or you will see something like { Object... } printet out instead.